# Не удается подключиться к google API

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, google-api

```
function GoogleCallback(jqueryObj, data) {
   console.log('data', data);
}

$(function () {
  $.ajax({

    url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0?key=*ТУТ КЛЮЧ*&q=PHP&callback=GoogleCallback&context=?',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    error: function() {
      console.log(':(((');
    }
  });

});
```

`GwebSearch is not defined` на выходе в консоли.

**При прямом линке**

```
/* callback */
GwebSearch.RawCompletion('0', null, 400, 'invalid version', 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно без ключа,  попробуй так. У меня работает. Для варьирования количества результатов параметр rsz. По умолчанию идет small, он как раз и равен 4. Если поставить large будет 8.

```
function googleSearch(e){
        $.ajax({
        url:'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=large&q='+e+'&callback=GoogleCallback&context=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

В `e` строка поискового запроса.

Comment: Да, именно оттуда. Спасибо )Теперь работает, выдает 4 запроса. Можно как-то варьировать их количество?  И подскажите, что вы исправили чтобы заработало, на вид строка такая же

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?